# sql query with self joins being used in informatica

Tags: sql-server

input table has :

```
CODE    CATEGORY    COLOR
-1      3          Green
18578   2          Green
18578   3          Green
20032   1          Green
20032   3          Green
20032   2          Green
```

output table should have:

```
CODE    CATEGORY    COLOR
-1          3       Green
-1         100      Green
-1         200      Green
18578       3       Green
18578      100      Green
18578       2       Green
20032       1       Green
20032       3       Green
20032       2       Green
```

what kind of query should be used, used a variety, but

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: for each key, we need 3 colors to be generated, if the source table has onely 1, then we need to add 2 and then insert the 3 records into the target, if source has 2 record  we add one record and insert 3 records, if the source has all 3 records, do nothing

Comment: And why 100 and 200?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-aggregate the original table, then conditionally unpivot to get the extra rows

```sql
INSERT YourTable
  (CODE, CATEGORY. COLOR)
SELECT
  t.CODE,
  v.CATEGORY,
  'Green'
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.CODE,
      cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.CODE
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CATEGORY = 100
      WHERE cnt <= 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 200
      WHERE cnt = 1
) v
```

Comment: the reason, we need 100,200 or 300 is, if the source has 1,2 or 3 in the category, then we use it as it is, the category should have 1,2 and 3 for the code in the target, if 1 is missing we need 100 in the target , if 2 is missing we need 200 and if 3 is missing 300 in the target

Comment: And is there only these fixed `CATEGORY` values, or are there more?

Comment: yes, its fixed 3 max